# can anybody know why the call back function executes later?

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
var name = req.body.username;
var pass = req.body.password;

Account.countDocuments({username:name, password:pass}, function(err , count){
  if(count > 0){
    Account.find({username:name, password:pass}, function(err,data){
        prof = data[0].profile;
        console.log(prof + "Executes Second");  // here it executes second
    })
    console.log(prof+" Executes First");  // here it executes first
    res.render("index",{
        url : prof,
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log("no account");
    res.render("login",{
        error : "You dont have a account !"
    });
  }
 })
})
```

/*I just passing the image url to ejs file but I want to know why the call back func. executing later*/

Comment: Later than what? That is what callbacks are for—code to be executed when the function they’re passed to is ready to call them.

Comment: Because it will call back when it completes a thing? It's in the name.

Comment: now I had edited the question with comments

Comment: that means in Account.find() , at which step it calls back ?

Comment: I don't know how your `Account.find` method works or does, but if it takes a callback, it means that it will execute the passed in method when it's done doing some task of indeterminate length (like talking to a server to find an account, which depending on latency and response times might take anywhere from a millisecond to seconds or minutes). So a callback is well named: it will _call you back_ when it's done whatever job you wanted it to do.

Comment: The “executes first” executes first because it’s the next code to be executed after the call to “Account.find”. The callback to “find” will be executed whenever “find” calls it. I *suspect* you’re actually asking how async programming works in general.

Comment: @PRANESH Whenever “find” calls it. It’s likely the source for “find” is available so you could look.

Comment: @DaveNewton basically it finds, and only it moves then why there is the delay in calling

Comment: No, the callback is executed by the `find` method when it's done. Any line below that is unrelated to it and after calling find with the callback for later it will just continue on the next lines. The lines within the callback represent the code to execute when find is done doing its business.

Comment: Asynchronous 101. You order a pizza to be delivered. You place the order and you try to eat it. You do not wait for it to be made or delivered. The callback is the delivery driver ringing your doorbell to say it is done and ready to eat. Any logic that needs to wait for the code inside the callback needs to be triggered when the pizza has been delivered. If you don't you are eating an undefined pizza.

Comment: @somethinghere nice I got it

Comment: @epascarello Awesome example bro... Visulaized everthing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of how the event loop and stack call of JavaScript are built. I find this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript) very insightful. And I hope it will be the same for y'all.

but to explain it in very few words I'd say:
"
Let's suppose we have

```
function calledFirst() {
  (args), function() {
    console.log("Executes Second")
  }

function calledSecond() {
  console.log("Executes First")
}

function main() {
  calledFirst()
  calledSecond()
}

main()
```

The stack defines the order of execution of the functions and expressions. When a callback function is triggered it is executed outside of the stack and its result will then go to a queue from which it will be taken only once the stack is empty. Therefore even if it is a very simple operation, once **calledFirst** is called, it will be executed outside of the stack and then the result will stay in the queue because in the meanwhile the stack will already be present **calledSecond** with no callback function so you will see its result before the result of **calledFirst**"